# Wordpress Multisite SubSites: 302 Moved Temporarily

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I've recently changed the domain for Multisite website, I followed the instructions from here https://wpengine.com/support/how-to-change-a-multi-site-primary-domain/

Now, only main site`(http://domain.com/)` works but the other sites `(e.g: http://domain.com/es/)` are giving error "302 Moved Temporarily" and redirected to itself `(http://domain.com/es/)`.

Under `Network Admin` > `Sites` > `Edit`(for sub site i.e: `http://domain.com/es/`) > `Settings`, Siteurl and Home is also same as the main URL rather than `http://domain.com/es/`. I tried to change it to `http://domain.com/es/` but, opening the `http://domain.com/es/` URL updates it back to `http://domain.com/`

in my wp-config.php file these lines are commented out

```
//define('WP_HOME','http://fruitionpartners.eu');
//define('WP_SITEURL','http://fruitionpartners.eu');
```

Is there something I am missing? Please help.